# Extended Query Protocol in Psycopg2

Tags: python, database, postgresql, psycopg2, libpq

Does Psycopg2 support Extended Query Protocol ? If yes, can you please share documentation on how to use this mode?

Comment: `psycopg` i.e. `psycopg3` does, see here [psycopg3 adaption](https://www.psycopg.org/articles/2020/11/24/psycopg3-adaptation/).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer: https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/issues/1401

> No, you can't. Psycopg2 is completely built around client side binding and simple query protocol.

> Using the extended query protocol is a breaking change and pretty much a complete redesign. This is what happened in Psycopg 3.

Indeed, I've tested psycopg3 and was able to use the Extended Query Protocol.